# Why function is empty that's passed form ThemeContext

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to call toggleTheme function from themeContext. But it is empty function.

themeContext.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  theme: 'light',
  toggleTheme: () => {}
});

export function ThemeContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    console.log("ToggleTheme")
    setTheme(theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

//App.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { ThemeContext, ThemeContextProvider } from "./theme/themeContext";
import styled from "styled-components";

const AppContainer = styled.div`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.textPrimary};
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.background};
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  transition: all 0.5s; 
`;

const Button = styled.button`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.textPrimary};
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.background};
  border: 2px ${({ theme }) => theme.textPrimary} solid;
  float: right;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

function App() {
  const { theme, toggleTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(theme);
    console.log(toggleTheme);
    toggleTheme();
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContextProvider>
      <AppContainer theme={theme}>
        <Button onClick={() => handleClick()}>
          Switch to {theme === "light" ? "Dark" : "Light"}
        </Button>
        {/* rest of your component code */}
      </AppContainer>
    </ThemeContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `useContext(ThemeContext)` can only be used as a child of `<ThemeContextProvider>` You can't have both in the same component

Comment: Thanks @Konrad. Yes, it is. After create component for ThemeSwitcher, it is working.